DHCP server on a Juniper MX5
I'm trying to configure a basic DHCP server on a Juniper MX5. Although I have a significant experience of configuring DHCP servers on a branch Juniper devices, the standard approach mysteriously doesn't work: as soon as I switch to DHCP on a client host, the connectivity breaks, the only protocol that is working is ARP (the host even cannot ping a router). The most astonishing aspect is that I assign the same IPv4 address as static as the MX5 gives as dynamic, yet when received by DHCP it doesn't work.
I've found a book where it's explained how to configure DHCP on a high-end JunOS devices using vlan-ranges, dynamic profiles and bound variables; is this even possible without all of this ?
I'm using the following config:
[access]
profile local {
    authentication-order none;
}
address-assignment {
    pool vlan116v6 {
        family inet6 {
            prefix 2a04:8681::/64;
            dhcp-attributes {
                dns-server {
                    2001:4860:4860::8844;
                    2001:4860:4860::8888;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    pool vlan116v4 {
        family inet {
            network 10.10.116.0/24;
            range vlan116-dynamic {
                low 10.10.116.51;
                high 10.10.116.249;
            }
            dhcp-attributes {
                domain-name hosting-telecom.uk;
                name-server {
                    8.8.4.4;
                    8.8.8.8;
                }
                router {
                    10.10.116.1;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
[system services]
ssh;
dhcp-local-server {
    dhcpv6 {
        overrides {
            interface-client-limit 100;
        }
        group vlan116 {
            interface irb.116;
        }
    }
    pool-match-order {
        ip-address-first;
    }
    authentication {
        username-include {
            mac-address;
        }
    }
    group default {
        interface irb.116;
    }
}


It look you're missing the binding between the dhcp-local-server group and the access-profile which links to the address-assignment.
Try:
set system services dhcp-local-server group default access-profile local


Yeah, thanks, it's really missing. Although adding this logical connection didn't help. I fully realize that my post looks like "some guy is posting fairy tales on the internet", but I double- and triplechecked the settings - ip/masks/gw are correct. I've even wiresherked the dhcp client machine - nothing is working except ARP: every other frame is just sent without answer. I requested a working MX DHCP config from a friend of mine working at ISP, and got it, but it's hugely integrated with radius and requires the whole network scheme rebuild, since it's done with flexible vlan tagging etc.

Try removing the authentication stanza from dhcp-local-server and see if anything changes.  Not sure why you’d need this if you’re not doing subscriber interfaces.
